# How to shorten a string

Tags: bash, find, rename, xargs

Let's say I have following files: *1.html*, *2.html* and *3.html* and I want to rename them to *1.html-bak*, *2.html-bak* and *3.html-bak*. To do this I run following command:

```
find . -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} {}-bak
```

Everything is OK, files are renamed as expected.

The question is how to rename them back to `*.html` instead of `*.html-bak`?

How to remove last 4 chars from string?

Comment: You don't need `xargs`; `find . -name '*.html' -exec mv '{}' '{}-bak' \;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `${file%-*}` to get the desired file name back. The following code loops through all files whose name end with `html-bak` and performs the renaming by removing everything after the last dash:

```
for file in *html-bak
do
   echo "mv $file ${file%-*}" # <-- using "echo" for safety. Remove once checked
done
```

`${var%-*}` strips the shortest match of `*` from back of `$var`. That is, removes until the first dash `-` is found starting from the right:

```
$ file="1.h-tml-bak"
$ echo ${file%-*}
1.h-tml
```

You of course could also use the length, to get everything but the last 4 characters:

```
$ echo ${file:0:-4}
1.h-tml
```

Comment: I don't think the `0` is necessary (`"${file::-4}"` works for me). On older bash negative lengths aren't supported but you can do `"${file::{#file}-4}"`.

Comment: As the only `bash`-specific element of the answer, `${file:0:-4}` can also be replaced with the standard `${file#????}`. `${var:x:y}` is useful when `x` and `y` aren't constants, since there is no concept of counting in patterns.

Comment: Thanks for both comments, I completly agree. @chepner I guess you mean `${file%????}` (last 4 chars, not first ones). My impression is that it is best to use the `${file%-*}` for this specific case, as it is more general: this way, we could remove all extended file name as `file-bak`, `file-backup` and so on. That's why I added the `${file:0:-4}` as another possible approach, not the recommended one.

Comment: Yes, `%` instead of `#`. You'd think I'd remember the difference better by now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel you can run:

```
find . -name '*.html-bak' -print0 | parallel -0 mv {} {.}.html
```

This works even if the filenames contain ', " and space.

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

A personal installation does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: This is exceedingly awesome and completely overpowered for this question.  Still thanks for posting, parallel is neat!